# update R presentation in Rpubs instead of creating a new presentation

Tags: r, rstudio

I use Rpubs to publish a lot of my reports and studies that I write in Rmd format, if I ever want to change it, I just go to the file and republish it. However when I write R presentations, every change I make when I want to publish it, it RStudio won't give me the chance to update, I always need to create a new url. Is that something anyone has solved here?